# Understanding $Lemma \, (1.6)$ to imply Lipschitz Continuity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

In the book "The theory of Ordinary Differential Equations" I'm having trouble understanding $Lemma(1.6)$ which assets Lipchitz Continuity defined below, specifically the gap in my understanding is within the operation taken within $(2.)$,specifically speaking the specifics of my question can be seen in $Conclusion$The initial proof of the lemma can be seen within $(1.7)$.
$$Definition(1.1):$$
A set $S$ in a vector space over  is called a convex set if the line segment joining any pair of points of lies entirely in $S$.

$ \, , \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,     Lemma \,  (1.6) $:

If $\frac{\partial f(t,y)}{\partial y_j}$ $(j = 1,2, ... , n)$ exist are continuous and satisfies the condition: $|\frac{\partial f(t,y)}{\partial y_j}|$ $<$ $L_o$ $(J = 1,2,..., n)$ for $(t,y)$ $\in$ $I$ x $D$ where $I$ is an interval, $D$ is a region and $L_o$ is a constant , and if $D$ a convex open set then $|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)| < nL_o|y_1-y_2|$ for $t$ $\in$ $I$ $y_1$ $\in$ $D$, and $y_2$ $\in$ $D$.
$$(1.7)$$
$$ Proof \, of \,  Lemma(1.6): \, \,$$
Fix $t$ $\in$ $I$ and $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $D$. Then, $\theta$$y_1$$+$($1$- $\theta$)$y_2$ $\in$ $D$ $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$ since $D$ is convex. The author initially sets $g(\theta)=f(t,\theta y_1 + (1-\theta)y_2)$. Then Derives the following equality in $(2.)$
$$(2.)$$
$$\Bigg\{g(0)=f(t,y_2), \, \, \, \, \, g(1)=f(t,y_1)
 \, \, \, \, \, \frac{dy}{d \theta}=\sum_{}^{}(y_1 j)(y_2 j)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_j}(t, \theta y_1 + (1-\theta)y_2)\Bigg\}.$$

$$Interjection:$$ At this stage within the proof I was initially able to observe on a geometrically level that our region $D$ being a convex open set implies that we have a vector space within $R^{n}$ that initially allows us to have line segments joining points within our vector space that doesn't have any boundary, and since $D$ is a convex open set it must satisfy Lipschitz Continuity on our respective interval. Visualization of our Vector space can be seen within $Figure (1.1)$.

$$Figure (1.1)$$.
[image]

$$Remark:$$ My major observations on an rigorous basis beginning at the beginning of $(1.6)$ with the initial function:$g(\theta)$ from the initial definition of a Convex Set implies that we have a set within $R^{n}$ which contains our Vector Space $S$. Referring to $Definition \, (1.1)$ this notions that $y_1$ and $y_2$ were combined. Therefore from this result we have our function:$g(\theta )$. Further observations can be seen within of operations within $(2.)$ can be seen in $Interjection(2)$.
$$Interjection(2)$$:
The function $g(\theta)$ can be initially expressed as the following matrix in $(1.1)$
$$(1.1)$$

\begin{bmatrix}
f((t,\theta y_1)) + ((1-\theta)y_2))\\  
f((t,\theta y_2)) + ((1-\theta)y_3)\\
f((t,\theta y_3)) + ((1-\theta)y_4))\\        
f((t,\theta y_4)) + ((1-\theta)y_5))\\        
f((t,\theta y_5)) + ((1-\theta)y_6))\\        
f((t,\theta y_6)) + ((1-\theta)y_7))\\        
f((t,\theta y_7)) + ((1-\theta)y_8))\\
\end{bmatrix}.

Algebraic operations on $g(\theta)$ initially imply the following:
$$g(\theta)=f(t,\theta y_1 + (1-\theta)y_2).$$
$$g(0)=f(t, 0) y_1 + (1-0)y_2) => g(0)=f(t_1,y_2), \, \, \,  g(1)=f(t_1,y_2)).$$

$$Conclusion$$
My initial misunderstandings of the steps taken to prove the Lemma begin with the infinite series, and the initial function $g(\theta)$. Addressing $g(\theta)$ could there be other values for function that could have been initially used ? My further initial question was how was the series derived in $(2.)$ ? . I managed to make this initial observation about the series:

$$\frac{d y}{d \theta}=
\sum_{}^{}(y_1 j)(y_2 j)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_j}\begin{bmatrix}
f((t,\theta y_1)) + ((1-\theta)y_2))\\  
f((t,\theta y_2)) + ((1-\theta)y_3)\\
\, \, .
f((t,\theta y_n)) + ((1-\theta)y_n))\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$.